# Emoji copyright

Tags: emoji

I am developing an app that uses emoji and have some legal concerns.

- Who has the copyright for Emoji?
- Is there a license for using the images?

Comment: While I can understand why people might view this question as off-topic, copyright concerns related to software development seem to fit under the "practical, answerable problems that are _unique_ to the programming profession" category in the FAQ. Including emoji in a program for usage by other people would likely have a different legal meaning from simply utilizing the emoji yourself, and thus this sort of question is indeed at least close to being unique to "the programming profession".

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130045/138822

Comment: I thought that stackoverflow is for sharing information regarding software development. licensing and copyright is a huge part in software that is to be published. So just like syntax information is shared legal issues should be allowed to be shared

Comment: Peter Edberg from Apple wrote: "As previously stated, Apple would like to make the Apple Emoji font -  
and the glyphs therefrom - widely available using a license that makes  
it possible for anyone to change it as they see fit or to combine its  
glyphs with those from another font, without Apple acquiring any  
rights to such changes." https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/emoji4unicode-fontdesign/eqY3_p_ET8E

Comment: I assume we are talking about the “Apple Color Emoji.ttf” here. @Archimedix, http://stackoverflow.com/a/22949517/1389680 explains that your Edberg quote was referring to a different font - and that there is no license for “Apple Color Emoji.ttf” available.

Answer (score 20):

Emoji are generally rendered on your device by locally stored fonts licensed to the end user for use with their operating system. In this case copyright is irrelevant as your software is not distributing the artworks any more than my answer to this question is distributing the Arial typeface.

If you need to render Emoji on a system that has no such font, then you're looking at copyright issues as you'll need to distribute original artworks.

To distribute fonts outside of a licensed OS or create and distribute image files from them would be subject to the license that comes with the OS and/or its font files.

For example the [Gemoji](https://github.com/github/gemoji) project has made bitmap version of Apple Emoji and is [copyright of Apple](https://github.com/github/gemoji/blob/master/LICENSE) - whether that means you can use them as long as you add a copyright notice or not, I cannot tell you.

By contrast, Android's Emoji font is licensed under the Apache 2 license, so I think (and I'm not a lawyer) that you may use the font according to those terms in your own work. I am using [Android Emoji as a web font here](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode) if you're interested.

Worth noting too is the [Phantom Emoji](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/374397522/phantom-open-emoji) project which is creating an open source set of full colour emoji.

Comment: Here's a TL;DR Legal version of the Apache 2 license: https://tldrlegal.com/license/apache-license-2.0-(apache-2.0)

Comment: I have mailed Peter Edberg from Apple and he [told me](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22949517/1389680) that the “Apple Color Emoji.ttf” was never considered for licensing.

Comment: Tim are the android images you use available for download somewhere? Or does it have to be extracted from an android rom ?

Comment: My work is out of date now. This post is two years old. But everything I got, I got from the official Android project code as font files.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using these from font then no, but if you copied these to your project resources - add notice to your about window. If you want to use them on Windows (from Mac to Windows) you must.

Answer (score -7):

Emoji are just fancy emoticons, and last I checked, emoticons aren't generally protected by copyright (because of their small size; to my knowledge, you normally can't copyright individual words, which is what emoticons/emoji are equivalent to. You can trademark them, though). However, I doubt they could be properly trademarked, either, considering their generic nature/common usage. A logo/etc. that contains emoji could probably be trademarked (and it's almost certain that at least one has, though I can't think of any off the top of my head), but I don't believe the emoji itself could.

At the very least, you're as likely to encounter legal trouble when using emoji as you are when quoting an internet meme.

Comment: Also, if the Unicode standard can include emoji, I think you're fine. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji#Emoji_in_the_Unicode_standard

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. all fonts (including emoji) is basically a mapping between a code (unicode) to a glyph. I'm sure the mapping itself is free (0xe056 -> SMILING FACE WITH SMILING EYES) but what about the pictures? these may be someones property just like some proprietary fonts...

Comment: Unicode standard does not include fonts, because they are original copyrightable artworks. It makes a point of saying so: 

"The fonts and font data used in production of the Unicode Standard may not be extracted, or used in any other way in any product or publication, without permission or license granted by the typeface owner(s)"

- [See source](http://www.unicode.org/charts/fonts.html)