# License of "Apple Color Emoji.ttf"

Tags: ios, fonts, licensing, emoji

What's the license of OS X Lion's `/System/Library/Fonts/Apple Color Emoji.ttf`?

In [this posting](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/emoji4unicode-fontdesign/eqY3_p_ET8E) Apple's Peter Edberg says:

> As previously stated, Apple would like to make the Apple Emoji font - 
>   and the glyphs therefrom - widely available using a license that makes
>   it possible for anyone to change it as they see fit or to combine its 
>   glyphs with those from another font, without Apple acquiring any
>   rights to such changes. The only conditions we want to impose are: a)
>   The name "Apple Emoji" can only be used for the original unmodified
>   font; if the font is modified or combined with another font, the
>   result must have a different name (without "Apple" in it). b) The
>   original font, or one derived from it or incorporating parts of   it,
>   can not be sold as a stand-alone package. (However, it it could be
>   included as part of a system which is sold as a package). Otherwise a
>   third party should be free to use the font, or to adapt   it, modify
>   it, extend it, distribute it, etc.

However, at the time of that posting (2009), Apple had not decided about the actual license. I tried to find out now, but I could not find a more official license statement.

[**Update 2014-03-12**: I have now mailed Mr. Edberg and asked for clarification.]

Comment: Just did a through search and couldn't find a thing on that license. It seems apple never followed through with it. Although phantom emoji is another source you can use and here is the link https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/374397522/phantom-open-emoji they have their own license. As far as apple license there are none given away yet.

Comment: I have now flagged this question to be moved to https://opensource.stackexchange.com/, where it fits.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Mr. Edberg has answered me (my emphasis):

> The font being considered for licensing as per the emoji4unicode posting [...] was not “Apple Color Emoji”, which was **never considered for licensing**. Rather, it was a separate black & white “Apple Emoji” font mainly developed as part of the proposal to Unicode and ISO 10646 for the addition of emoji characters, in order to provide glyphs for use in the code charts etc. As far as I know it is not a font that ever been included in shipping Apple products.

So the answer is that there is no license for 'Apple Color Emoji.ttf' available.

IANAL, by the way.

**Update 2018-02-06:** [According to Twitter posts](https://twitter.com/Sam0711er/status/958793819495059460), Apple has started enforcing that now in the App Store. Sam Eckert reports there:

> I’ve just been on the phone with the App Review team regarding the Emoji issue. Apps are NO LONGER ALLOWED TO USE EMOJI in non-keyboard based situations. Means if your app displays emoji anywhere without a user having it typed in, it’s illegal and will be rejected.

Comment: So, did you end up using it?

Comment: @EirikHoem, I was asking this for [TextSecure](https://whispersystems.org/#encrypted_texts), and they [decided to use the Android Emojis instead](https://github.com/WhisperSystems/TextSecure/issues/592#issuecomment-51909739).

Comment: @RobertPollak Hi there, so, given that there is no license, does that mean that everyone is free to use the artwork present in Apple Color Emoji?

Otherwise, how could companies like Slack have the Apple Color Emoji artwork appear in not just their iOS apps, but also their Android and Windows apps?

Comment: @Vexir The missing license means that using the pictures could be prosecuted by Apple. It seems they didn't do this yet, though. I guess everyone is just taking the risk - even TextSecure/Signal nowadays.

Comment: I don't understand why anybody is taking the risk even though plenty of alternative emoji fonts exist...

Comment: Hi I see apps like Telegram uses the apple font. So how can it do that? Is it legal?

Comment: Moreover, I see Signal now uses apple icons as well! Does this mean it is ok now? Thanks!

Comment: @ch271828n Yes, Signal uses the Apple icons since 2015, see my old comment. At least this (and the use by Telegram) gives a hint about their risk assessment.

Comment: @RobertPollak Thanks very much! So my app will use them as well :)

Comment: @RobertPollak Sorry for another question - do you pay money to apple for approval, or directly use them? Thanks!

Comment: @ch271828n That's a good point. I have no idea whether e.g. Signal or Telegram pay for their use.

Comment: @RobertPollak Thanks very much! I originally thought you are in the Signal team :)

Comment: @jobukkit because emojis are not technical stuff and Apple ones are cooler than anything out there. Sorry for the non-technical answer.