# iOS emoji for android app. Is it legal?

Tags: android, ios, keyboard, emoji

Before this question gets marked as a repeat, let me say I have gone throughout the existing questions on StackOverflow, and I have not found a proper answer. I am aware that there are many apps that enable the iOS design emojis on android phones, and I'm also aware that I could potentially add them to my android app, but my question is: Is it legal to use Apple's emoji icons in my android app? Do I need some sort of special permission from them?

**Whatsapp is a good example. They use Apple's emoji icon designs in their keyboard for both iPhone and Android. Could i too do the same for my app's keyboard? Would it be legal to do so, or will I have any issues in the future?**

Thanks.

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22337295/license-of-apple-color-emoji-ttf

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal matters, not programming.

Comment: The [emoji you're referring to](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji) is definitely not Apple/iOS-specific.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Emoji are Unicode characters, so should work if you have written your application in a Unicode aware manner all the way through (for ex, by using NVARCHAR types on your database layer)

Comment: But the question was especially about "iOS design emojis" and "Apple's emoji icons", so it's a question about the [glyphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glyph), not the corresponding Unicode characters.