# How to detect emoji support on Android by code

Tags: android, emoji, android-api-levels

By code, I can make a button that inserts these 3 emojis into the text: ⚽️

On many phones when the user clicks the button, though, **the problem is that ⚽️ displays as [X][X][X]**. Or even worse, it displays only three empty spaces.

I would like to disable and hide my own built-in emoji-keypad on Android devices that do not display emojis correctly. Does anyone knows or have a tip on how to detect in code if a device has emoji support?

I have read that emoji is supported from android 4.1, but that is not my experience....

Comment: I suspect the X's are from an Apple iPhone or iPad, etc. I had a Galaxy for years and everyone in my family had iPhones. I would always get messages and then the X's rather than the emoticon it was supposed to be.

Comment: I might be an issue with iphone vs android emojis, but I would like to try detect the support of an emoji-symbol by code, I think that would be safest.

Comment: If you already ended up solving your problem, I would be interested in seeing the details of what you did.

Comment: Check this https://github.com/google/mozc/blob/master/src/android/src/com/google/android/inputmethod/japanese/emoji/EmojiRenderableChecker.java

Answer (score 11):

I just implemented a solution for this problem myself. The nice thing with Android is that it is open source so that when you come around problems like these, there's a good chance you can find an approach to help you.

In the Android Open Source Project, you can find a method where they use `Paint.hasGlyph` to detect whether a font exists for a given emoji. However, as this method is not available before API 23, they also do test renders and compare the result against the width of 'tofu' (the [x] character you mention in your post.)

There are some other failings with this approach, but it should be enough to get you started.

Google source:

- https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/+/master/java/src/com/android/inputmethod/keyboard/emoji/EmojiCategory.java#441
- https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/+/master/java/src/com/android/inputmethod/keyboard/KeyboardLayoutSet.java

Comment: flag/penguin test failed on my 4.1 device, which definitely has emoji :(

Answer (score 10):

**Based on Jason Gore answer**:

For example create boolean *canShowFlagEmoji*:

```
 private static boolean canShowFlagEmoji() {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        String switzerland = "\uD83C\uDDE8\uD83C\uDDED"; //  Here enter Surrogates of Emoji
        try {
            return paint.hasGlyph(switzerland);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodError e) {
            // Compare display width of single-codepoint emoji to width of flag emoji to determine
            // whether flag is rendered as single glyph or two adjacent regional indicator symbols.
            float flagWidth = paint.measureText(switzerland);
            float standardWidth = paint.measureText("\uD83D\uDC27"); //  U+1F427 Penguin
            return flagWidth < standardWidth * 1.25;
            // This assumes that a valid glyph for the flag emoji must be less than 1.25 times
            // the width of the penguin.
        }
    }
```

And then in code whenever when you need to check if emoji is available:

```
if (canShowFlagEmoji()){
    // Code when FlagEmoji is available
} else {
    // And when not
}
```

Surrogates of emoji you can get [here](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode), when you click on detail.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to test this yet, but getting some actual code in an answer is definitely an improvement over just links.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative option might be to include the Android "*Emoji Compatibility*" library, which would detect and add any required Emoji characters to apps running on Android 4.4 (API 19) and later:    https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/preview/emoji-compat.html

Comment: Thank you but that Library is not fun to deal with. You have to do special timely initializing of the library not to mention other concerns

Answer (score 0):

```
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final boolean isEmojiRendered;
        if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.M) {
            isEmojiRendered = paint.hasGlyph(emoji);
        }
        else{
            isEmojiRendered = paint.measureText(emoji) > 7;
        }
```

The width > 7 part is particularly hacky, I would expect the value to be 0.0 for non-renderable emoji, but across a few devices, I found that the value actually ranged around 3.0 to 6.0 for non-renderable, and 12.0 to 15.0 for renderable. Your results may vary so you might want to test that. I believe the font size also has an effect on the output of measureText() so keep that in mind.

The second part was answerd by RogueBaneling here [how can I check if my device is capable to render Emoji images correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25261310/how-can-i-check-if-my-device-is-capable-to-render-emoji-images-correctly)